# Check if home.php and set home.php as page_on_front

Tags: theme-development, functions, conditional-tags

I want to include a custom inline js on home page only.
I havent set home page from reading section.
I am using home.php file.

```
function print_my_inline_script() {    
   if (is_home() && wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
      ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
            $('.carousel').carousel();
            $('.item').hover(function(e){
                $(this).find('.summary').stop().fadeTo('fast',1); 
            },function(){
                $(this).find('.summary').stop().fadeOut('fast'); 
            });
        });
      </script>
      <?php
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_my_inline_script' );
```

This doesnt work. `is_front_page()` doesnt work either.

I have already done `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` after loop.

I have one more question. I know home.page overrides `index.php` and works as home page. 
But I dont want my users to get confused when they change options in `reading` section.

I have found this,

```
update_option( 'page_on_front', $post->ID );
update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
```

but it needs an ID and I dont have any page, so I dont have any id.

So, I need a way to set check if user is in `home.php` (home page) and since using home.php overrides the reading section options, any workarounds for that ?

Answer (score 2):

### First issue:

> I want to include a custom inline js on home page only. I havent set home page from reading section. I am using home.php file.

I will assume that by *home page*, you actually mean *site front page*. In that case, you don't really care about `is_home()` or `home.php`, as these apply to the **blog posts index**, regardless of whether you are on the *site front page* or some other page.

See also:

> I have one more question. I know home.page overrides index.php and
>   works as home page. But I dont want my users to get confused when they
>   change options in reading section.

Again, the confusion here regards *home page* as *site front page* versus *blog posts index*. Refer to [the Template Hierarchy for site front page display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display) for further explanation.

User reading settings will have no impact, if you choose the correct conditional with which to enqueue your script.

### Second issue:

This conditional in your callback:

```
if ( is_home() && wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) )
```

1. `is_home()`: You need to use `is_front_page()`, if you intend to target the *site front page*
2. `wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' )`: this seems to be unnecessary; you merely need to register your script with `jquery` as a *dependency*

### Third issue:

> I have found this,
>
> ```
> update_option( 'page_on_front', $post->ID );
> update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
> ```
>
> but it needs an ID and I dont have any page, so I dont have any id.
>
> So, I need a way to set check if user is in home.php (home page) and since using home.php overrides the reading section options, any workarounds for that ?

This is, essentially, `_doing_it_wrong()`. You should have no need to override user settings. Just pick the right conditionals:

1. To target the *site front page*, use `is_front_page()`
2. To ensure that the *site front page* is displaying a *static page*, use `'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' )`.
3. If the front page is set to display a *static page*, then the *user will have created and assigned a static page to use*. To determine the ID for that page, use `get_option( 'page_on_front' )`.

### Putting it all together

1. Add your script to a `custom.js` file in the Theme directory somewhere.
2. Add a callback hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts()`:

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse58196_enqueue_custom_script' );`
   ```
3. Inside the callback, enqueue your custom script based on the correct conditionals:

   ```
   function wpse58196_enqueue_custom_script() {
       // If we're on the site front page, and the front page displays a static page
       if ( is_front_page() && 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {
           // Enqueue custom script, with jQuery as a dependency, and output in the footer
           wp_enqueue_script(
               // handle
               'custom-carousel',
               // path
               get_template_directory() . '/custom.js',
               // dependency array
               array( 'jquery' ),
               // version
               '1.0',
               // in footer?
               true
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is more likely related to  `wp_script_is()`.

Try this instead

```
function aa_home_scripts() {
    if(is_home()){
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'app-home',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.home.js',
            array('jquery'), // declare jQuery as dependancy
           '1',
           true // flag to add to footer
       );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'aa_home_scripts');
```

Comment: No , `is_home` returns false

Comment: I just tested and it worked fine for me. home.php is the base for the blog. So if you change the Reading page to a specific page it will load that template. If you want the front page / homepage of your website and you set a front page then use the `is_front_page()`

Comment: `is_front_page()` is false too. Moreover your method does not use inline js.

Comment: Try `is_blog()` function mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
if ( is_front_page() || is_page_template( 'home.php' ) {     
     //javscript stuff...

}
```

Comment: Technically home.php is not a page template, it's the main page for the blog. `is_page_template()` will only return true if a page has a custom template that you select from the sidebar.